# Polymer 2.x. Extend properties of polymer element

Tags: polymer-2.x

Using the Polymer 2.x syntax to create a class that extends another class (which is extended from Polymer.Element), is it possible to define a default set of properties in the super class which can be overridden in the child class?

My attempt was:

```
class ParentClass extends Polymer.Element
   static get properties() {
      return {
        myProperty: {
           type: String,
           value: "x"
        }
      }
   }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
   static get properties() {
      return {
        myProperty2: String
      }
   }
}
```

When ParentClass is created the expectation is that myProperty == "x", and when ChildClass is created to have myProperty == "x" and have an additional property of myProperty2.  In practice, ChildClass only has myProperty2.

Maybe ChildClass should call the super class properties and merge properties, but I can't find a way to call the super class perhaps because it is declared static (?).

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: Yes, it helped me to realise what an in idiot I am :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `parent-class` inside `child-class` element. Then, to access the `parent-class`'s property simply call as that property is on `child-class` like: `this.myProperty`.

You can also override the property value in `child-class`.

Here is a demo in plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7kkitdcCZkbySNClxgTo?p=preview.

> **Note**: The properties and observers of a subclass(child class) are
>   added to those defined by the superclass(parent class).
>
> A subclass can also inherit a template from its superclass.